# Getting number of pixels from raster that fit a certain criteria

Tags: raster

I have downloaded many tiles of MODIS' MCD64A1 Burnt Area GeoTIFF data per year and am trying to count the number of pixels that are not -2, -1 or 0 (to calculate approximate total area burnt each year).

I have tried direct approaches to make statistical analysis, such as using geopandas and pandas on Python, but to no avail, since it returns errors that say I must allocate 90 plus pebibytes of memory (probably due to the data being nation-wide).

What are some ways to extract the ***number of*** pixels from multiple rasters that are not certain values?

Comment: If you have decided against GeoPandas for meeting this requirement, then what GIS software are you trying next, and wanting to ask about in this particular question?

Comment: I haven't necessarily decided against it - since I'm new to programming, I'm certain I'm doing something wrong and there is another, better way. I wondered if there were better ways of making simple calculations on such big datasets, and looked on the internet, but I could not find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the error is due to trying to load all data at once.

Can you process a single tile individually in a loop instead? I guess there is overlap,  which complicates things. Also, how are you going to save the result if it needs so much memory? Here's a possible work flow:

1. divide the area into rectangles to search for tiles,  and then
2. merge all tiles that are in the rectangle into a VRT,  and then
3. process each VRT (count pixels) and
4. clip the resulting data to the rectangle.

Repeat until you cover the whole area. That should reduce memory usage. Bigger rectangles will require more memory, but reduce redundancy. This sounds like a fun project!

For **1**, use a GIS to divide the whole area into rectangular tiles. In QGIS, you can go to *Vector - Create Grid*. Then loop through the rectangles:

For **2**, find the tiles overlapping a rectangle. You could find their bounding polygons, and then find the overlap of these polygons with your new rectangle. Merge all raster tiles that are in the rectangle into a VRT.

For **3**, process the VRT the way you want to (fire).

For **4**, clip the VRT with the rectangle (maybe not necessary).

You might need to swap **3** and **4** to get a unique result.

For **5**, save the clipped data or merge it as a big, big VRT, or polygonise it to reduce memory requirements, etc.